# How to use polymorphic_path in a functional test in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing, rails-3-upgrade

I'm trying to use `polymorphic_path` in a functional test in Rails 3.

At first I would get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `polymorphic_path' for #<ArticlesControllerTest:0x492f17c>
```

And then I added

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

The `undefined method error` stopped, but  now regular paths, like `article_path(article)` for example stopped working:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `default_url_options' for #<ArticlesControllerTest:0x33ccbe0>
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:102:in `url_options'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:131:in `url_for'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:195:in `article_path'
```

I used to be able to use polymorphic_path normally in Rails 2 by including

```
include ActionController::UrlWriter
```

How can I get this to work in Rails 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I need to include:

```
include ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

and set:

```
default_url_options[:host] = 'www.example.com'
```

I found out via this post that answers a similar issue
http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/04/29/rails-3-rake-and-url_for/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.polymorphic_path
```

? :)

Comment: It looks like it should work, but I tried it and it didn't. I'll keep looking and I'll come back to update

Comment: ```include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers```

This worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when refactoring some Rails4 tests to make them model-agnostic. I found that

```
something_path(obj)
```

worked but

```
polymorphic_path(obj)
```

didnt. None of the above suggestions worked for me either. I did find that this did, however:

```
@controller.polymorphic_path(obj)
```

This is in the context where `self` is a descendent of `ActionController::TestCase`.

Another way to work around this is do define a delegation method in the controller test class:

```
def polymorphic_path(*args) 
  @controller.polymorphic_path(*args)
end
```