# In Rails, what's the URL helper for an unknown model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, urlhelper

I'm trying to get the path in Rails to a model that I don't necessarily know the class of in a rake task (so it's not in an .erb).

I know that I can do this:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.<model>_path(model)
```

But what if I don't necessarily know the model? It seems not Rails-y to switch on the model.class or any other such inspection. I'm just looking for the default path or url to the model.

Edit: To clarify what I mean by default path, it's the href you get when you do link_to; i.e., you can do this:

```
<%= link_to "my model", @model %>
```

without specifying a url helper like model_path. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. There is no 'default route' for a model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, `link_to` calls `url_for` to get the path for the given arguments.

If you call `url_for` with a model, it'll forward further to `polymorphic_path` or `polymorphic_url`.

So something like this should work, if you just want the path

```
task :some_task => :environment do
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  # ...

  path  = polymorphic_path(some_model_instance) # => e.g. "/widgets/42"
end
```

You can also just use `url_for`, but you'll have to define the `:host` option. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7020478/167996) for more